# get rows from csv by matching to Dictionary keys python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am trying to return an item from all rows in a CSV that contain a match to each key in a dictionary using python 2.7.

I have tried the following code

```
with open(r"root\to\file", "r") as inFile:
    for k in myDict.keys():
        reader = csv.reader(inFile)
        result = [row[11] for row in reader if row[3] == k]
        print(result)
```

as an output I get one successful list and then the correct number of empty lists.

Can anyone tell me why it is only working for the first key?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it's only working for the first key is that when a file is read, there is a file position that is at the beginning of the file when the reading starts and at the end of the file when the reading ends. After the first key, the reader has reached the end of the file and doesn't go back to the beginning of the file automatically.

I see three solutions at least

**Load a list of all the rows**

```
with open(r"root\to\file", "r") as inFile:
    row_list = list(csv.reader(inFile))
for k in myDict:
    result = [row[11] for row in row_list if row[3] == k]
    print(result)
```

**Store only the matching items in a dictionary**

This is my favorite solution. Each row is only examined once

```
from collections import defaultdict
result_dict = defaultdict(list)
with open(r"root\to\file", "r") as inFile:
    for row in csv.reader(infile):
        if row[3] in myDict:
            result_dict[row[3]].append(row[11])
for k, result in result_dict.items():
    print(k, result)
```

**Go back to the beginning of the file at each iteration**

The advantage is that we don't need to store anything, but it is unusual
to perform many `file.seek` operations, so I'd prefer to store the rows
if the size of the csv file is not too big.

```
with open(r"root\to\file", "r") as inFile:
    reader = csv.reader(inFile)
    for k in myDict:
        inFile.seek(0)
        result = [row[11] for row in reader if row[3] == k]
        print(result)
```

Comment: thank you for your help! I have attempted your top solution, however I still only receive one answer, now without the empty lists... any ideas?

Comment: I don't see how it could fail. Did you copy and paste the solution? Perhaps there is only one dict key that is equal to a `row[3]`? You could print `row_list` to see what it looks like.

Comment: I was passing variables though functions, when I copy/paste your solution it provides what I need.

Answer (score 0):

**Can anyone tell me why it is only working for the first key?**

reader = csv.reader(inFile) opens the file and start reeding it from start to end. It will then leave the cursor in the end. In the following iterations it has nothing to read.

**How to fix this (quick-fix-version)?**

```
with open(r"root\to\file", "r") as inFile:
    for k in myDict.keys():
        reader = csv.reader(inFile)
        inFile.seek(0) # move cursor to start
        result = [row[11] for row in reader if row[3] == k]
        print(result)
```

## Explanation

I will exemplify what I mean. First let me provide you with some sample data I write to a file (csv-format).

```
import csv

dict_ = {"1":1, "2":3}

data = """date,id,weight
01/01/1991,1,293
01/02/1991,2,291
01/03/1991,3,289
"""

with open("output.txt","wt") as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Non-working example:

```
with open("output.txt") as f:
    for keys in dict_:
        reader = csv.reader(f) # <-- Opens file and reads it (cursor in end)
        print([i for i in reader])

## Output
# >> [['date', 'id', 'weight'], ['01/01/1991', '1', '293'], ['01/02/1991', '2', '291'], ['01/03/1991', '3', '289']]
# >> []
```

Instead use this:

```
with open("output.txt") as f:
    for keys in dict_:
        reader = csv.reader(f) # <-- Opens file and reads it (cursor in end)
        f.seek(0) # <-- Return cursor to 0 (cursor is now in the start)
        print([i for i in reader])

## Output
# >> [['date', 'id', 'weight'], ['01/01/1991', '1', '293'], ['01/02/1991', '2', '291'], ['01/03/1991', '3', '289']]
# >> [['date', 'id', 'weight'], ['01/01/1991', '1', '293'], ['01/02/1991', '2', '291'], ['01/03/1991', '3', '289']]
```

Or simply read it to a local variable first:

```
with open("output.txt") as f:
    csvdata = list(csv.reader(f)) #or this

for key in dict_.keys():
    [print(i) for i in csvdata if i[1] == key]

## Output
# >> ['01/01/1991', '1', '293']
# >> ['01/02/1991', '2', '291']
```

Comment: thank you for this very helpful explanation. I have accepted the answer of Gribouillis as it provides more options. I will up vote this answer but as I have <15 points it will not show. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You need to reopen the file each time. So invert the with and for statements.

For efficiency I would recommend using pandas to read the csv so you can query the resulting dataframe many times.